# Computer shutting down unexpectedly

Tags: shutdown, crash

So I used to have a problem back when I ran Windows: my computer would randomly shut down with no sort of warning, it wouldn't show me any other error than "computer shut down unexpectedly", which didn't exactly help. I finally decided to switch completely to ubuntu (great choice I won't go back :D), however now after a couple of weeks it started happening on ubuntu as well >:( Here I seem to get a few more error codes though.

```
Apr 19 18:17:01 toimi CRON[4751]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
\00\00\00\00\00 ...
```

[Here is how it looks in syslog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNPTA.png)

This doesn't tell me much (I am a linux newbie); is there anywhere else I can look for relevant logs?

Here's what I know is not the problem:

1. Graphics card
2. Power supply
3. SSD/Hard drive
4. RAM
5. Overheating

if it's in any way relevant I switched my CPU-cooler right before this started happening on ubuntu. Also when I did that I reseated to make sure no pins were bent etc.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: Your syslog link doesn't show what you intended it to show. Please retry. And, for the things that you say are NOT the problem, how do you know that they're not candidates? Do you know how hot your cpu and computer get? You'll need temp monitoring software installed to check that. Did you use thermal paste when you changed the cpu cooler? Are you running on AC or battery?

Comment: Well, i've tried replacing the RAM and PSU with parts i know work. I've tried running without the graphics card(running on the processors built in graphics). Also i've tried running it without any harddrives at all connected, with a usb-drive. So i'm pretty sure none of those are the problems. And i've monitored the temps, a lot. They are not the problem. 
AC.

And what do you mean? :o The syslog link i sent was a screenshot from var/log/syslog when the crashed happened. basically the same as the code i included. http://imgur.com/a/EjcDo

Comment: The syslog link takes us to a page with all zeros... not a syslog listing. What temps are you running? Did you use thermal paste?

Comment: @heynnema I think he used **copy** and paste for the syslog.

Comment: @heynnema exactly, that is all the info i got. :) it's just a bunch of zeroes. My CPU temps are around 29-35° in idle, under heavy load its roughly 65°. (It was 98° before i swapped cooler). GPU is 35-45°

Comment: @JonBrave yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Given this started immediately after you replaced the CPU cooler, I can only point to a problem with the new CPU cooler (fan not running, bad contact with the CPU, lack of thermal paste, no liquid in a liquid cooling device, etc.) as the most likely source of the problem.

Comment: hmm yes this is what i thought tbh. But it feels unlikely :o it had pre-applied thermal paste and the temps are good. However since it used to happen a lot when i ran windows i feel like it's probably the same problem that has just re-emerged.

Comment: I would say most times I have had random crashes like this using Windows (and I have had a few over the years) it has turned out to be overheating....

Comment: @Toimi Temperature from the CPU sensor can change a lot very quickly -- if you start a process that loads all your cores to maximum, a CPU that has a cooling issue can go from "just fine" to "emergency shutdown" in a minute or so.

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon okay :o is there a better way to monitor the temperature?

Comment: @Toimi One thing you might try is opening a real time temperature monitor, then starting a CPU-intensive task and watching the temperature readout.  You should have time to see the temperature climbing before you get to shutdown conditions.  Another option would be to find a temperature monitor that writes a log file (ideally, with updates at least once a second).

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon alright! I'll try this! Thank you:)

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon It never seems to crash during stress-tests. As we speak i'm running stress with the command stress -c 4 which before would've overheated my system. Right now i'm at slightly under 80 degrees and the system is just fine. processor usage is at 100% on all cores (edit: tried stress -c 8 aswell and it was no problem at all)

Comment: Okay, I'm out of ideas.  I'm much better at making stuff mysteriously start working than I am at reproducing mysterious crashes.